# Samsung SSD, TRIM and Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, ssd, samsung, trim

In light of a recent issue raised in regards to Samsung SSD firmware relating to TRIM and the related launchpad bugs for Ubuntu..
Bug# 1465663 'libata Samsung SSD 8 series TRIM blacklist' and the original
Bug# 1338706 'Samsung SSD 840 failed to get NCQ Send/Recv Log Emask 0x1 failed to set xfermode (err_mask=0x40) on upstream kernels >= 3.12'

The issue appears to be with queued TRIM and not sequential TRIM on the drive, however the problem for my drive (Samsung 840 PRO) may be related to any TRIM command. Does someone know ?

I was after some advice on whether I should do one of the following, a combination of the following or something else:

1. Disable TRIM in my /etc/fstab (taking away the 'discard' option I currently have)
2. Put parameter 'libata.force=noncq' in the grub boot command line (GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT) to stop queued trim
3. Wait for the updated kernel blacklist - that from my understanding blacklists the Samsung 840 Pro from some or all TRIM functions - depending on what the blacklist entry states.

My computer is a dual boot (Windows 7 and Ubuntu 15.04) using the Samsung PRO 840 SSD (512 GB) as the primary drive. The drive has four partitions - boot (EFI boot partition  FAT32), Windows (NTFS), and two EXT4 partitions (for linux).
A secondary 1TB SATA mechanical platter drive is used for data.

I have the original firmware on the Samsung SSD - as i have never bothered to update it.

Update 27 June 2015:
Checked my logs and I do not have any specific errors.
Also - my old SSD firmware must not allow NCQ (queued TRIM) as I have this in the log:
"ata1.00: failed to get NCQ Send/Recv Log Emask 0x1"
Also, the blacklist update patch is due in kernel version 3.19.0-22.22.
No errors when I manually run FSTRIM -av.