# Run e2fsck automatically to fix all errors during boot with Samsung SSD 850 EVO 500GB

Tags: dual-boot, ssd, 16.10, samsung, trim

Almost each time that I switch from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 16.10 which I installed on a dual boot laptop Ubuntu wants me to

```
e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sdb5
```

Can I automate this during startup? If yes, how? Fixing problems shall be automatically done (I have to press <kbd>A</kbd> in order to have all errors fixed automatically). Other posts state that this is done automatically during startup but does not seem to work in my case. The volume is a SSD Samsung MZ-75E500B/EU 850. I also read there [were issues with these SSD types](https://askubuntu.com/questions/864565/have-the-linux-kernel-bugs-that-caused-data-loss-when-using-a-samsung-850-pro-ss) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866683/on-ubuntu-16-04-with-samsung-850-evo-ssd-is-any-post-configuration-needed). I did not experience data loss yet. I read that the [trim feature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_(computing)) [has to be activated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18903/how-to-enable-trim). This was done automatically in my case. Errors remain. Could anyone explain to me on how to **de**activate trim or fix the problem in another way?

Here is my /etc/fstab

```
UUID=NUMBERS /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=NUMBERS  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=MORENUMBERS none            swap    sw              0       0
```

There is no discard option is described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/638307/samsung-ssd-trim-and-ubuntu-15-04).

[image: Samsung Magician output.]

Comment: In Windows, do you have a driver to access EXT2/3/4 partitions? Have you done the firmware update on the SSD? You don't want to deactivate trim.

Comment: Yes, I have Ext2Fsd 0.69.1035-09.14 installed.

Comment: I did not update my firmware, I only checked a moment ago using the Samsung tool. It is already the latest.

Comment: Windows driver? Bypass the Samsung tool and manually check the web site to see if that's really the latest firmware.

Comment: Samsung Magician. See image. I would like to avoid a firmware update if not really necessary.

Comment: I deinstalled Ext2Fsd 0.69.1035-09.14. Until now the problem did not reoccur.

Comment: You still didn't answer my question about a Windows EXT2/3/4 driver. I believe you that the Samsung Magician says you are current... I asked that you manually check their web site for later versions. You can always read the changelog to see what, if anything, got fixed. You want to stay current with firmware updates.

Comment: I did answer. Please read again. I cannot find the firmware on http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools.html. 850 PRO is not 850 EVO, right?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I mistook Ext2Fsd as the firmware version, but it's the Paragon driver... which I found corrupts EXT2/3/4 partitions... but you've uninstalled it, and that may fix your problem. Samsung Magician should be v5.0, dated Jan 4, 2017, and at the top of page http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/evo-850-series-120gb-2tb there's a link for updated software dated 1/18/2017 at http://orcaservice.samsungmobile.com/SWUpdate.aspx

Comment: The Samsung Update application seems to download software for Samsung laptops. I have an Asus laptop where I installed the SSD by myself. I think removing the Paragon driver solved this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

I've found that Windows EXT2/3/4 drivers can cause corruption on Ubuntu partitions.

The user had Paragon Ext2Fsd 0.69.1035-09.14 installed, and has now uninstalled it.

I suspect that will take care of the problem.